# Laravel Photo Validation on Max Rulew

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my validation rule. It passes the required rule but I want it to show an error on max file limit, however, the error message that it displays is required and not max file size limit. Thanks for your help!

```
$this->validate($q, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'photo' => 'required|max:2048|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
    'photo_thumb' => 'required|max:2048|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
    'orderby' => 'required|numeric'
], ['photo_thumb.max' => ' Your photo is too large, must be less then 2MB']);
```

Comment: try delete image

Comment: it show this error ' The photo thumb failed to upload.  '  instead of my custom message

Comment: Are you sure your image is uploading? i think it doesn't, this could be for many things, but just as a guess, check if you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

Comment: Thank for your response my question. I found the problem by increase file upload size in php.ini. :)